# Normal Map problem - looks low poly

Tags: normals, normal-map

What on earth am I doing wrong here [image]

I followed Jayanam's Blender Bake Normal Map Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQPjIGncXcM
but everytime I do this I get a low poly looking normal map.

I must be misunderstanding something fundamental here so sorry if this is a nooby question. I've marked seams on the UV of the low poly mesh, editted the extrusion and the max ray distance but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shade smooth both.
Use a sub div modifier in high poly if needed

Comment: Thanks that's worked fine! So simple, really appreciate it though